# iBeacon access in background mode

Tags: ios, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I am accessing Gelo iBeacon,Its working fine in foreground mode but how to get ibeacon range or region monitoring when the app is in background mode.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try project->Capabilities->background Modes-> make it on-> checkmark Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories

Comment: Actually, iBeacon requires location background mode, not Bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

Generally `iOS` lets you monitor for `beacons` in the background but not range for them.  Ranging only works in the background for a few seconds after a monitoring event.

Details on detection times and steps needed to set up background monitoring are [here.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method it will work for background as well as background

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you ask for always access to location manager.

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
{
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

DO NOT use "Location Updates" or "Uses Bluetooth LE accessory" as this might result in rejection from the app store. We are not using ranging, but just monitoring, and this worked fine for us.